# Conditional that tests for a dictionary key's presence is always False

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

I made a function that consumes two dictionaries, `curr_stats` and `weekly_result`.  If there are any keys in `weekly_result` that aren't in `curr_stats`, the function is supposed to just print `invalid_msg`, with no mutation of `curr_stats`.

But the `if` statement on the 5th line of my code doesn't seem to be working. It's supposed to trigger the next `if` statement, so no mutation of `curr_stats` occurs.

```
def update_standings(curr_stats, weekly_result):
    invalid = 0
    point_counter(weekly_result)
    for team in weekly_result:
        if team in curr_stats == False:
            invalid = invalid + 1
    if invalid > 0:
        print(invalid_msg)
    else:
        for team in weekly_result:
            curr_stats[team] = curr_stats[team] + weekly_result[team]
```

Comment: @matteo-piano the original code is equal to `team in curr_stats and curr_stats == False` and the second part is `False`, see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: @PawełKordowski ohh I see, alright thanks thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, [all comparisons have the *same* precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), including `in`.
What's happening is [comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), a special form intended to test transitive relationships like in math class:

```
if x_min < x < x_max:
    ...
```

As Paweł Kordowski pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884411#comment72871193_42884411), the above comparison chain is mostly equivalent to:

```
if x_min < x and x < x_max:
    ...
```

(There is one difference:
The "equivalent" code might evaluate `x` twice, while the comparison chain evaluates `x` exactly once.)

In your case, the comparison chain is:

```
if team in curr_stats == False:
    ...
```

...which is (mostly) equivalent to:

```
if team in curr_stats and curr_stats == False:
    ...
```

This is only true if `curr_stats` contains `team` *and* `curr_stats` is empty... which should never happen.

The problem with your code is the `== False` --- in part because it turned a comparison into a comparison chain, but mostly because you never needed it in the first place.
Python provides the `not` keyword for when you want a Boolean's opposite.
Your conditional statement should read:

```
if team not in curr_stats:
    invalid = invalid + 1
```

One last suggestion:
This function can be made even shorter by getting rid of the `invalid` counter and just returning as soon as an invalid `team` is found.
(Once the you've discovered that `weekly_result` is invalid input, you probably don't care if it's "*even more* invalid".)
I also used [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to simplify the final `for` loop:

```
def update_standings(curr_stats, weekly_result):
    point_counter(weekly_result)
    for team in weekly_result:
        if team not in curr_stats:
            print(invalid_msg)
            return
    for team, result in weekly_result.items():
        curr_stats[team] += result
```